# Xcode parsing JSON wit underscore

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I try to parse JSON in Xcode 6 and my code looks like this:

```
NSData *jsonClusterHealth = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/_cluster/health?pretty=true"]];

id jsonCHealth = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonClusterHealth options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
ClusterStatusLabel.text = [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"status"];
//NumberOfNodesLabel.text = [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"number_of_nodes"];
//ActiveShardsLabel.text = [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"active_shards"];
```

So, everything works great until I uncomment the last two lines, it crashes the app with the following error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013 2014-12-12 11:00:35.447 FnHAdmin[22139:1077781] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013'
```

As I figured out the reason is underscore in object key of json... So what is the problem in Xcode with json keys containing underscore??? And the main question is how to fix it (I can not remove underscore in JSON, so the solution must be in Xcode)...

Comment: does `jsonCHealth` have object for keys `@"number_of_nodes"` and `@"active_shards"`?

Comment: Drop the JSON code parsed

Comment: @Akhilrajtr sure it has!

Comment: Can u provide the crash log?

Comment: From the name `number_of_nodes` and `active_shards` one would assume that these objects are numbers and not strings.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr 
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013
2014-12-12 11:00:35.447 FnHAdmin[22139:1077781] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013'

Comment: Looks like the values for the keys `@"number_of_nodes"` and `@"active_shards"` are of `NSNumber` type. Try this, `NumberOfNodesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"number_of_nodes"]];`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr They are numbers... How can I fix it then?!))))

Comment: @Akhilrajtr You are right!!! Please post is as an answer I will confirm it as right!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crash log it seems like object  for the keys `@"number_of_nodes"` and `@"active_shards"` are of NSNumber type. Try,

```
NumberOfNodesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"number_of_nodes"]];
ActiveShardsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonCHealth objectForKey:@"active_shards"]];
```

Comment: can I ask you another question?
Here ia JSON:"indices" : {
"fnh_mainbeta" : {
"index" : {
"primary_size_in_bytes" : 355671123,
"size_in_bytes" : 355671123
},

How to get to primary_size_in_bytes?

Comment: Try this, `NSNumber primarySize = [[[[JSON objectForKey:@"indices"] objectForKey:@"fnh_mainbeta"] objectForKey:@"index"] objectForKey:@"primary_size_in_bytes"];`